# Adding custom attributes to ReturnParameter using reflection or IL

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I am trying to create some types on runtime using IL. I have an original `MethodInfo` which I have to replicate.

```cs
var parameters = OriginalMethod.GetParameters();

MethodBuilder methodBuilder = Builder.DefineMethod(
    $"<{OriginalMethod.Name}>k__BackingMethod",
    OriginalMethod.Attributes,
    CallingConventions.HasThis,
    OriginalMethod.ReturnType,
    parameters.Select(i => i.ParameterType).ToArray()
);

foreach (var attribute in OriginalMethod.GetCustomAttributesData().ToCustomAttributeBuilder())
    methodBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attribute);

foreach (var attribute in OriginalMethod.ReturnParameter.GetCustomAttributesData().ToCustomAttributeBuilder())
    methodBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attribute); // <---- Problem here

ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
// Some code removed for brevity

return methodBuilder;
```

As you can see, I can successfully copy the method level custom attributes. I can even get the attributes on `ReturnParameter`. However, I cannot seem to add new attribute to `ReturnAttribute`. Using the above code, the return attribute is applied as a regular method attribute. Any idea how I would do something like this?

EDIT: Added code for `ToCustomAttributeBuilder`

```cs
internal static CustomAttributeBuilder[] ToCustomAttributeBuilder(this IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> CustomAttributes)
=> CustomAttributes.Select(attribute => attribute.ToCustomAttributeBuilder()).ToArray();

internal static CustomAttributeBuilder ToCustomAttributeBuilder(this CustomAttributeData CustomAttribute)
{
    var attributeArgs = CustomAttribute.ConstructorArguments.Select(a => a.Value).ToArray();

    var propertyArgs = CustomAttribute.NamedArguments.Where(i => i.MemberInfo is PropertyInfo);
    var propertyInfos = propertyArgs.Select(a => (PropertyInfo)a.MemberInfo).ToArray();
    var propertyValues = propertyArgs.Select(a => a.TypedValue.Value).ToArray();
    
    var fieldArgs = CustomAttribute.NamedArguments.Where(i => i.MemberInfo is FieldInfo);
    var namedFieldInfos = fieldArgs.Select(a => (FieldInfo)a.MemberInfo).ToArray();
    var namedFieldValues = fieldArgs.Select(a => a.TypedValue.Value).ToArray();
    
    return new CustomAttributeBuilder(CustomAttribute.Constructor, attributeArgs, propertyInfos, propertyValues, namedFieldInfos, namedFieldValues);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `ToCustomAttributeBuilder`?

Comment: @vc74 Added the code. Is there anything else you need?

Comment: Shouldn't `methodBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attribute)` be `returnValueParameterBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attribute)`?

Comment: I don't have a `returnValueParameterBuilder` though, nor can I find how to build it. Any pointers?

Comment: It seems to me like you're applying method attributes to a parameter. Try `ParameterBuilder returnValueParameterBuilder = methodBuilder.DefineParameter(0,                        ParameterAttributes.Retval, parameterName: null);`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Never even considered that 0 would be for `ReturnParameter`. Alway thought it would correspond to `this` and therefore not make any sense. Can you write an answer out of it so I can close the post?

Comment: It's just a little strange that it doesn't show up in dotpeek when I save the assembly.

Comment: Done, I'm wondering if there's not another issue in `ToCustomAttributeBuilder` but I don't have the tools nor the time to look into this, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the custom attributes to the return value parameter, not the method:

```
ParameterBuilder returnValueParameterBuilder = 
    methodBuilder.DefineParameter(0, ParameterAttributes.Retval, parameterName: null);

foreach (var attribute in OriginalMethod.ReturnParameter.GetCustomAttributesData()
                                                        .ToCustomAttributeBuilder())
{
    returnValueParameterBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attribute);
}
```

Comment: That define parameter with index 0 saved me. Thanks again!